# Timing numerical operations on large vectors. How to draw a fair comparison?

Tags: c++, performance, numerical

I am timing some simple numerical operations to decide how (i.e., using what tools from what library) I am going to implement a computationally intensive simulation. The code below computes the sum of two inner products of vectors using (1) MTL4 version 4.0.9486 as is (i.e., without `BLAS`), (2) `std::vector`s and `std::inner_product`, and (3) `std::valarray`s. I picked a toy example of this specific form because it seemed like ideal ground for MTL4's expression templates.

To narrow everything down to a single question, is the following comparison fair or it puts (unintentionally) any one of the three approaches at disadvantage? I was a bit surprised that (2) is faster than (1). Whether the overall simulation will be faster or not is a different story, of course.

If anyone has any suggestions for more thorough tests that might reveal the strengths or weakness of each approach, I am eager to try them out.

Pardon the macros in the code; they are just `std::cout<<` statements and calls to `<chrono>` utilities.

Thanks in advance.

**C++ code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/numeric/mtl/mtl.hpp>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    /* DOT PRODUCTS */
    constexpr int trials{15};
    std::vector<double> mtl_times(trials, 0.0), stl_times(trials, 0.0), valarray_times(trials, 0.0);

    constexpr size_t sz{10000000};
    double val = M_PI;
    mtl::dense_vector<double> m(sz, val), n(sz, val), p(sz, val), q(sz, val);
    std::vector<double> y(sz, val), z(sz, val), v(sz, val), w(sz, val);
    std::valarray<double> b(val, sz), c(val, sz), d(val, sz), e(val, sz);

    double x{0.0}, k{0.0}, aa{0.0};
    auto t0 = NOW
    auto t1 = t0;

    for (int i = 0; i < trials; ++i) {

        // MTL4 vectors
        t0 = NOW // call now() from <chrono>
        k = dot(m, n) + dot(p, q);
        t1 = NOW
        mtl_times[i] = DURATIONm // duration cast of (t1-t0).count()

        // STL vectors
        t0 = NOW
        x = std::inner_product(y.begin(), y.end(), z.begin(), 0.0) + std::inner_product(v.begin(), v.end(), w.begin(), 0.0);
        t1 = NOW
        stl_times[i] = DURATIONm

        // valarrays
        t0 = NOW
        aa = (b*c + d*e).sum();
        t1 = NOW
        valarray_times[i] = DURATIONm

    }

    std::cout << "MTL4: average time for dot product = " << std::accumulate(mtl_times.begin(), mtl_times.end(), 0.0)/mtl_times.size() << " msec\n";
    PRINTV(mtl_times)
    PRINTME(result, k)
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::cout << "STL vectors + std::inner_product: average time for dot product = " << std::accumulate(stl_times.begin(), stl_times.end(), 0.0)/stl_times.size() << " msec\n";
    PRINTV(stl_times)
    PRINTME(result, x)
    std::cout << '\n';

    std::cout << "valarrays: average time for dot product = " << std::accumulate(valarray_times.begin(), valarray_times.end(), 0.0)/valarray_times.size() << " msec\n";
    PRINTV(valarray_times)
    PRINTME(result, aa)

    return 0;
}
```

**C++ Output:**

> MTL4: average time for dot product = **180.333 msec**
>
> mtl_times =
>   177   175 174 174 175 178 176 185 184 174 175 179 175 216 188
>
> result: 1.97392e+08
>
> STL vectors + std::inner_product: average time for dot product = **58.6 msec**
>
> stl_times = 56    55  56  57  57  56  57  56  57  55  55  58  56  58  90
>
> result: 1.97392e+08
>
> valarrays: average time for dot product = **64.4 msec**
>
> valarray_times = 63   64  63  64  65  63  63  63  64  63  63  63  64  64  77
>
> result: 1.97392e+08

For the record, MatLab performs well:

**MatLab code:**

```
trials = 15;
times_ms = zeros(1, trials);

sz = 1e7;
val = pi;
x(sz) = val;
x(1:end-1) = val;
y(sz) = val;
y(1:end-1) = val;
v(sz) = val;
v(1:end-1) = val;
w(sz) = val;
w(1:end-1) = val;

z = 0;

for i = 1:trials

    tic
    z = x*y' + v*w';
    times_ms(i) = toc*1e3;

end

avg_time = sum(times_ms)/length(times_ms)
times_ms
z
```

**MatLab output:**

> avg_time = **56.0687 msec**
>
> times_ms = 56.8919   57.2052   55.3179   55.5126   55.7660   55.3982   55.1044   55.4809 57.7229   56.1902   57.3888   56.5263   55.2830   55.4926   55.7501
>
> z = 1.9739e+08

This is not surprising since built-in operations are optimised, however there are other obstacles associated with using MatLab in the simulation.

Comment: If you look for speed you can create a parallel version of the inner product algorithm and utilize all your cores, not just one.

Comment: Be aware of data cache and instruction cache hits and misses.  Search the web for "Data Cache optimizations". One should be able to get better performance by using an array and conscious of the data cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computing dot products over and over will probably be memory-bound.  It'd be better to compare something like matrix multiplication if you're trying to get a rough sense of the speed differences you can expect.  Dot products are also straightforward enough that you can just inspect the assembly code to see what's going on; I'd encourage you to do this.

Your comparison is slightly unfair to valarrays; you make two arrays, then you add them together, then you take their sum.  It's probably better to compute the two sums and add them.  (I don't know how to avoid the extra scan of the whole array using the valarray interface.)

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful comments. And, you are right, merging the operations for the `valarrays` brings down the time at the same level as for `std::vector`, which is reassuring. I thought it wouldn't matter because of the `+=` operator, but I would have seen that this is not the case had I looked at the assembly...